# C++ Templates and inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a class structure like this:

```
class MyImportantClass {};


class BaseA 
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

class CustomA : public BaseA
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

class CustomB : public CustomA
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

class CustomC : public CustomB
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};
```

So the classes derived from `CustomB` need to create object of classes derived from `MyImportantClass`. Additionally `CustomC` needs to create object of classes derived from `CustomB`.

At the moment I derive from the Custom-classes and override the virtual functions. But nearly all of the code is the same except the creating of the new object.

Now I decided to use templates. My Classes now look like this:

```
class BaseA 
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

class CustomA : public BaseA
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

template <class T>
class CustomB : public CustomA
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};

template <class T, class ...temps>
class CustomC : public CustomB<T>
{
public:
  virtual void myFunction();
};
```

But now I have the problem if I want to create a list of `CustomB` derived class objects I can not use `QList<CustomB>` (yeah, I use Qt so QList) I have to use `QList<CustomB<SomeMyImportantClassDerivedClass>`. So I need some way without passing a templateparameter to `CustomB`. If I would use `QList<CustomA*>` it would be logical incorret in my application. I want to keep it logical correct so other developers can read and understand my code easier.

I hope someone read this whole post and can help me.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot use ``QList<CustomC>``, as ``CustomC`` is not a type. But you gave the solution, which is ``QList<CustomC<SomeMyImportantClassDerivedClass>>``, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: Do you really need *seven* levels of inheritance for a *minimal* example of your problem? Have some respect for your readers' time!

Comment: Why you need a way not to pas a template parameter to `CustomC`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I just used the classes from my application and changed the names. sorry, next time I try so keep shorter

Comment: @Psy-Kai: Why "next time"? You can edit your post.

Comment: @AmiTavory: I can not use `QList<CustomC<SomeMyImportantClassDerivedClass>>` because I store Classes with diffrent template parameters. These Classes are all derived from `MyImportantClass`

Comment: @KerrekSB: a little bit better? I did not post much here so I dont know how much information I have to give and when it is too much.

Comment: "Quantity of information" is not the same as "amount of text". You should give a lot of information and avoid any kind of noise, if that makes sense. For example, is it really relevant to your problem that you use `class` rather than `struct`? If not, switch to `struct`, remove all that `public` noise, and each class definition fits readably on one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `QList<CustomA*> list`. This way you can add pointers to all subclasses of `CustomA` including `CustomC<whateverClass>`.

To add: 
`list.append( new CustomC<whateverClass> );`

But remember, since you call `new` you also have to `delete` your object, but since you're using QT, you could just give your new object a parent and have it deleted when it's parent is deleted.

Comment: This is the only solution I came to too. But for my application it is logically wrong to store CustomA*. I hoped there would be an other solution to keep logical correct. I tried multible inheritance to BaseB but I can not call the constructor of BaseB.